# Javascript/Jquery delegate click triggers video function twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video, onclick

I am building a site that loads html5 videos based on gfycat's api (go gfy!).
Having a bug where when certain videos don't play on clikc. Actually do they do play, but the click event happens twice, and causes the video to pause. The video will never play again. [Site here](http://gfygur.com)

Because the video is loaded after the page, I use delegate to add click event.
Code for handling click to play/pause:

```
jQuery(document).delegate('video.gfyVid', 'DOMNodeInserted', function () {
    $('video').on('click', videoPlay);
    $("[data-toggle='tooltip']").tooltip();

});


function videoPlay(){
    if(this.paused){
        this.play();        
    }else{
        this.pause();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using DOMNodeInserted event here, i don't get it??? What about: `$(document).on('click', 'video', videoPlay);` set outside DOMNodeInserted handler. BTW, you could check and see if DOMNodeInserted is not fired more than once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have more than one video, and the `DOMNodeInserted` event fires as you expect, you'll get multiple handlers bound to the same video. If you have an even number of handlers, you'll start with a `play()` and eventually end with a `pause()`, giving the appearance that nothing is happening.

Instead of listening for the `DOMNodeInserted` event, why not delegate the `click` event?

```
$(document).on('click', 'video.gfyVid', function() {
    if(this.paused){
        this.play();        
    }else{
        this.pause();
    }
}
```

Comment: I had a very similar piece of code yesterday and it didn't work, I assumed it was because the videos are loaded after the page is considered loaded. Oh well. You solved it! I will leave with more knowledge about javascript than I did 2mins ago.

Comment: If you tried `$('video.gfyVid').on('click', function() {...})`, then that wouldn't have worked, because you would have been trying to bind a handler to an element that doesn't exist. But using delegation as I have in my answer, the handler is actually bound to `document`, which you can count on being there at any time.